# jQuery Events not binding to knockout conditional elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, knockout.js

I have a simple `loggedIn` property as a `ko` binding as a boolean, so when a person is logged in (a check which has an async xhr to confirm server-side) an element in the header should be shown:

```
<!-- ko if: loggedIn -->
<div class="loggedin">
  <a class="logout">Log Out</a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->

<!-- ko ifnot: loggedIn -->
<div class="loggedout">
  <a class="login">Log In</a>
  <a class="signup">Signup</a>
</div>
<!-- /ko -->
```

The above works from a show/hide perspective, i.e. if `loggedIn` is `true` it shows the `Log Out` link.

The problem I'm running into is binding jQuery to the elements, even with `.on`:

```
$('.loggedin').on('click', '.logout', function () {
   // Never fires...
});
```

It will work if I refresh the page, but any dynamic change leaves me unable to bind to the click (or any other) event.

**UPDATE:** I've created [a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LzLC8/1/) to show the issue

Comment: The `if` (and `ifnot`) binding uses the children as a template. When the observable bound to it changes, then the children are re-rendered. So, any event handlers bound to the children would be lost. `if` is a good choice when you can't or don't want to bind the children (performance issues or bound to sub-properties that don't exist yet). In your case it looks like `visible` would be suitable as it just toggles the `display` style.  The other choice would be to specify your `on` such that the target is at a higher level (`$(".someParent").on("click", ".logout", function() { });` ).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I found was to use `ko`'s `visible`:

```
<div class="loggedin" data-bind="visible: loggedIn()">
   <a class="logout">Log Out</a>
</div>

<div class="loggedout" data-bind="visible: !loggedIn()">
   <a class="login">Log In</a>
   <a class="signup">Signup</a>
</div>
```

Which seems to work perfectly, allowing the elements to be bound to by jQuery without issue.

Answer (score 1):

One good way of doing this is to have a function in your vm that does the work instead of relying on jquery events.  Then bind the click event to your function.

```
<div class="loggedout" data-bind="click: someVMFunction">
<a class="login">Log In</a>
<a class="signup">Signup</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I agree, and tried binding through `ko`'s `click`, however it was still problematic when we added a drop-down to contain the login/signup. The other thing is this is on a central controller which we're trying to keep clean and separate dom concerns into a util file.

Comment: I understand, and from what I can see your code should be working so I am not what the problem is, I thought the click binding would be a good suggestion

Comment: I agree, and thank you. I was thinking there was something missing with my code until I found other post about similar issues (though none of which seemed to have a solution)